# Postgres extremely slow update

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I'm working my way through many curiously slow queries on my Postgres database (PostgreSQL 10.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit, Windows 10). Here is just one example: a very simple update that is taking an extraordinary amount of time to execute.

```
UPDATE
    "Prescription"
SET
    "DiscountList" = TRUE
WHERE
    "PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111'
    AND "DiscountList" = FALSE
    AND ("Id" IN (
            SELECT
                discount1_."PrescriptionId"
            FROM
                "Discount" discount1_
            WHERE
                discount1_."PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111'
                AND discount1_."DiscountBy" = 'Prescription'));
```

This query takes almost 52 seconds to complete (even when there is nothing to update)! You can see the [EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output](https://explain.depesz.com/s/UwXN). I have tried converting the sub-select to a join but it just gets worse (178 seconds). Obviously, this line sticks out in the analysis: `Index Scan using "Prescription_pkey" ... (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=2503751)`. That's 45 seconds right there. Why is it taking so long? Any recommendations on how to improve it?

Here are the table/index definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Prescription"
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "RecordVersion" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "RecordCreatedAt" timestamp without time zone,
    "RecordModifiedAt" timestamp without time zone,
    "CriterionType" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "DateCancelled" timestamp without time zone,
    "DateDispensed" timestamp without time zone,
    "DateSold" timestamp without time zone,
    "DiscountList" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "ExcludedReason" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "GroupNumber" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Insurer" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "NDC" character varying(11) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "PCN" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ProductName" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Quantity" numeric(19,4),
    "RxNumber" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ThirdPartyPaid" numeric(19,4),
    "TotalClaimPrice" numeric(19,4),
    "UPC" character varying(14) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "PharmacyId" uuid,
    CONSTRAINT "Prescription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "Prescription_PharmacyId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PharmacyId")
        REFERENCES public."Pharmacy" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE
);

CREATE INDEX "INDEX_Prescription_PharmacyIde60cffc4508643c09b6263ec4bdf0987"
    ON public."Prescription" USING btree
    ("PharmacyId")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE public."Discount"
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "RecordVersion" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "RecordCreatedAt" timestamp without time zone,
    "RecordModifiedAt" timestamp without time zone,
    "DiscountBy" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "DiscountedPrice" numeric(19,4),
    "DiscountReason" integer,
    "PharmacyId" uuid NOT NULL,
    "PrescriptionId" uuid,
    CONSTRAINT "Discount_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "Discount_PharmacyId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PharmacyId")
        REFERENCES public."Pharmacy" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE
    CONSTRAINT "Discount_PrescriptionId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PrescriptionId")
        REFERENCES public."Prescription" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE
);

CREATE INDEX "INDEX_Discount_PharmacyIdc94000327c3b434caa4c2807d67e66a0"
    ON public."Discount" USING btree
    ("PharmacyId")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX "INDEX_Discount_PrescriptionId6cd5c38e038c47c2b3f15e9e8ae59dc7"
    ON public."Discount" USING btree
    ("PrescriptionId")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

And here are the relevant configuration settings:

```
shared_buffers = 1GB
temp_buffers = 64MB
work_mem = 128MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
seq_page_cost = 1.0
random_page_cost = 1.0
effective_cache_size = 32GB
```

All tables were recently vacuumed and analyzed.

Comment: Where does the sort+unique come from? (NULLs?) Anyway: use `EXISTS()` instead of `IN()` And add the PharmacyId to the JOIN condition, instead of repeating it.

Comment: `ERROR:  column discount1_.PrescriptionId does not exist` :: Please post correct DDL.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Sorry, I had removed a bunch of columns for brevity and accidentally removed PrescriptionId from the Discount table. This has been fixed.

Comment: Can you show us your solution using a JOIN?

Comment: update
      "Prescription" 
   set
      "DiscountList" = TRUE 
   from
      "Discount"
   where
      "Prescription"."Id" = "Discount"."PrescriptionId"
      and "Prescription"."PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111' 
      and "Prescription"."DiscountList" = FALSE 
      and "Discount"."DiscountBy" = 'Prescription';

Comment: That will update the targer rows more than once. (it is an N->1 relation)

Answer (score 1):

First step: use `EXISTS()` instead of `IN()` , and don't repeat the literal condition:

---

```
UPDATE "Prescription" dst
SET "DiscountList" = TRUE
WHERE dst."DiscountList" = FALSE
AND "PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111'
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM "Discount" ex
        WHERE ex."PrescriptionId" = dst."Id"
        AND ex."PharmacyId" = dst."PharmacyId"
        AND ex."DiscountBy" = 'Prescription'
        );
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it slightly better (43 seconds). [EXPLAIN output](https://explain.depesz.com/s/n9ks). I'm still way off target, though.

Comment: Isn't that what this does?
CREATE INDEX "INDEX_Prescription_PharmacyIde60cffc4508643c09b6263ec4bdf0987"
    ON public."Prescription" USING btree
    ("PharmacyId")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

Comment: How many prescriptions have ` "PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111' AND "DiscountList" = FALSE`?  How many does PostgreSQL think there are?

Comment: 85,908,800 rows total. 8,461,801 rows (9.85%) for "PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111' AND "DiscountList" = FALSE. I'm not sure how many rows PostgreSQL thinks there are. Based on the query plan, it looks like it may be somewhere around 2,500,000 rows. pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup shows 86,453,298 (total).